# Pygame input Korean text

Tags: input, text, pygame, cjk

I have to input Korean texts on my pygame program. I tried 'https://github.com/Nearoo/pygame-text-input' and many other things, but it didn't work for me. Do you know how?

Comment: Have you finished this function?Thanks.I want to input Chinese texts...